# Network Flow - Minimum flow in a network

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

I have a directed graph **G=(V,E)** with a source **s**$\in V$ and a sink **t**$\in V$. There is a minimum capacity (lower bound) **l $_{e}$** for each edge in **G**. There are no upper bounds on the edges.

In a course that I took, the professor told that to find a minimum flow -

1) We need to assign a large capacity to all edges and find flow **f**
2) Construct **G $_{1}$** where all edges are reversed and each edge has capacity **f$_{e}$ - l$_{e}$**
3) We need to then find the max flow from t to s in G$_{1}$ that is f$_{1}$
4) Then, the  minimum flow in G is  **f-f$_{1}$**

> My question is-  Why can't we find a `s to t` path in `G` with the least
>   value of  l$_{e}$. The least value of l$_{e}$ would be the minimum
>   flow that could be pushed through the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have the following graph (in red are the minimum capacities):

[image]

The $(s,t)$-path with the lowest flow demand needs $1$ unit of flow, but the minimum flow is $4$. And the $(s,t)$-path with minimum sums of capacities has a sum of $2$, so this also doesn't work.